# Connect pod with static framework to another pod as dependency in podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

I have a framework that I connect to my project as a pod. 
I need to connect a Google Maps in the framework. I tried to make it in `podspec` file:

```
s.dependency 'GoogleMaps'
s.dependency 'GooglePlaces'
```

But I get an error during `pod install` that '*target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries*'.

I tried to add this code to `podfile`:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried to copy `GoogleMaps.framework`, `GoogleMapsCore.framework` and `GooglePlaces.framework` to my framework and connect them like that:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = "MyFrameworkFolder/GoogleMaps/*.framework"
```

but I get in error while compiling project which contains the pod: *could not build Objective-C module 'MyFramework'*

I tried to fix it in post install hook with

```
  if target.name.start_with?('MyFramework')
      config.build_settings["OTHER_LDFLAGS"] = '$(inherited) "-ObjC"'
```

but no effect.

Does anyone have an experience in solving problem like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CocoaPods 1.4.0 added the static framework podspec attribute that instructs CocoaPods to build a static framework instead of a dynamic framework **and** to depend upon static vendored_frameworks.

Add `s.static_framework = true` to your podspec.

More in the [CocoaPods 1.4.0 announcement blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.4.0/).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when working with Firebase dependencies, however I'm not really sure if the solution I found will apply your problem as well, so pelase, take this with a grain of salt.

Try to add these lines in your `podspecs`:

```
spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    "OTHER_LDFLAGS" => '$(inherited) -framework "GoogleMaps" -framework "GooglePlaces",
    "CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES" => 'YES',
    "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => '$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GooglePlaces/Frameworks",
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have deleted my dependencies from `podspec` and added `pod 'GoogleMaps'` in podfile of project. Then I edited podspec with the code above and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning dependency inside my podspec. After I added `spec.static_framework = true` I had error "MLKit module not found"

In my case I had to add **"HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS"** as well.

```
spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
"OTHER_LDFLAGS" => ["$(inherited)", "-framework MLImage", "-framework MLKitBarcodeScanning", "-framework MLKitCommon", "-framework MLKitVision"],
"CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES" => "YES", 
"FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => ["$(inherited)","${PODS_ROOT}/MLImage/Frameworks", "${PODS_ROOT}/MLKitBarcodeScanning/Frameworks", "${PODS_ROOT}/MLKitCommon/Frameworks", "${PODS_ROOT}/MLKitVision/Frameworks"],
"HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => ["$(inherited)", "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMLKit", "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore/Sources"] }
```